# issue with biofam3c data in SeqHMM

Tags: traminer

I have  the data which is `biofam3c` in package SeqHMM in list format. I wanted to see it in matrix form. I used this command

```
matrix_biofam3c= matrix(unlist(biofam3c), ncol=16, byrow= TRUE)
```

But its results was confusing . Then I also tried to change `matrix_biofam3c` into list using a command

```
U= as.list(as.data.frame(matrix_biofam3c))
```

it gives not similar results like given form in package (List of length 4). I request please, suggest the right way to make `biofam3c` in matrix data (like `biofam` in package TraMineR). And also how to convert it again so it becomes like list as it is given there.

Answer (score 0):

The data `biofam3c` is a list of three matrices that contain sequence data of three channels, namely `children`, `married`, and `left` (for left home). Tables `children` and `left` have binary data (children vs childless, left home vs with parents), while there are three states for `married`: `single`, `married`, and `divorced`.

The help page of `biofam3c` gives the code used to generate these three channels from the `biofam` data that ships with TraMineR. Note that this code assumes that we do not have divorced people living with their parents. The `biofam` data does not distinguish between divorced with and without children, nor between divorced who have left home and those who did not. See also the example in the help page of the `seqdistmc` function of TraMineR.

You can reconstruct `biofam` from the three channels using `interaction`

```
library(seqHMM)
data(biofam3c)
## the 3 channels
children <- biofam3c[[1]]
married <- biofam3c[[2]]
left <- biofam3c[[3]]

## Reconstructing biofam
bf.rec <- matrix(NA,nrow(children),ncol(children))
for (i in 1:ncol(children)) {
  bf.rec[,i] <- as.matrix(interaction(children[,i],married[,i],left[,i]))
}

alph <- seqstatl(bf.rec)
## reordering states as in biofam
alphabet <- alph[c(6,5,4,3,10,9,8,7,2,1)]
## creating a single state divorced as in biofam
bf.rec[bf.rec %in% alphabet[8:10]] <- "divorced"
alphabet[8] <- "divorced"
alphabet <- alphabet[1:8]
    
seq.bf.rec <- seqdef(bf.rec, alphabet=alphabet)
seqdplot(seq.bf.rec)
```

[image]

You get the same figure using the original `biofam`

```
## in biofam sequence data are in columns 10 to 25
library(TraMineR)
bf <- biofam[,10:25]
seq.bf <- seqdef(bf)
seqdplot(seq.bf)
```